# Making a Menu for each user Role in .NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have been doing typical menu from code behind where i just show and hide divs based on their role but code becomes very long cause i have to hide every single div of each role for each user.

My question is... Is there a better practice to do this? I also just found out about Login View, is this the way to go in Web Forms?

Answer (score 1):

Your code behind should not take the responsibility of altering how the View is displayed, that's the job of the view (and that's why asp controls exist).

One approach would be to have a logic that builds up a List and this list is passed as DataSource of an asp control.

Actually there's a good control that allows you to iterate a collection of elements defining a display template for each element in that list, here you can find the details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater?view=netframework-4.7.2

I hope this sets you in the right path.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do this is in a WebForms app is to use a [SiteMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/introduction/master-pages-and-site-navigation-cs).

A site map can be linked to roles, so that only those elements that are accessible for a user's roles are displayed.  And recent versions can be made to display reasonable cleanly, as divs that can be styled how you want (the original version generated a lot if inline styles).

For an MVC sitemap there are similar solutions, such as [this one](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider).